# Windows 7 Aero in Ubuntu Host Virtualization

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, aero

I'm looking to run Windows 7 inside my Ubuntu 10.04 installation through a virtualization client, I have tried Oracle/Sun's VirtualBox but it doesn't seem to allow aero because of the hardware acceleration etc.

Does anyone know of any virtualization software which can run a Windows 7 installation with aero enabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. Vmware workstation for Linux supports this.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox also supports running Windows 7 Aero mode as guest on a Ubuntu (Linux) host.

Take care of the following steps:

1. Goto Settings -> Display and increase the Video Memory to 128MB.
   Also enable 3D Acceleration and 2D Video Acceleration.
2. Increase the total memory from the System (if required)
3. Boot Windows 7 now, Install Guest Additions and make sure to install Direct3D Support. A warning will appear when you select Direct3D. Just click on **No** as for Aero safe mode installation won't help.
4. Restart Windows.
5. Goto to Personalize by right clicking on Desktop and choose a Windows 7 Aero theme.

This worked for me with VirtualBox 4.1.22 running on Ubuntu 12.04